# In Google Apps script I am trying to retrieve a value from a cell in a Google sheet but the value is undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The aim of the following function is to retrieve a value from a cell and call a different function based on the value. When I run it, it always runs the default function and it looks like it's not returning the value into the variable (survey) as this is shown as undefined when I debug the function, and the log value is null:

```
function hideOrShow() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var survey = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Store View 2022').getRange(3,1).getvalue;
  Logger.log (survey);
  if (survey='Delivery') {
    showCancellationColumns();
    }
  else if (survey='C&C') {
    showCancellationColumns();
    }
  else { hideCancellationColumns();}

};
```

Thanks Annette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that need to be changed in your code:

[`.getValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) (note the capital V--JavaScript variables are case sensitive) is a function, so it needs parentheses:

```
var survey = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Store View 2022').getRange(3,1).getValue();
```

That should solve the issue of `survey` being undefined.

When we test for equality (in an `if` statement, for example), we use [double](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) or [triple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) equals signs:

```
if (survey=='Delivery')
```

and

```
else if (survey=='C&C')
```

As written with a single equals ([assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)), `if (survey='Delivery')` will assign the value `'Delivery'` to `survey`.

Comment: Rookie errors! Thankyou! I'm more familiar with VBA, so GAS syntax sometimes trips me up

Answer (score 1):

It's just an error in the "getValue()" method

try this:

```
function hideOrShow() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var survey = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Store View 2022').getRange(3,1).getValue();
Logger.log (survey);
if (survey='Delivery') {
  showCancellationColumns();
  }
else if (survey='C&C') {
  showCancellationColumns();
  }
else { hideCancellationColumns();}

};
```